# How to implement an algorithm in java that returns the sum of the top k elements on the Stack in O(1) time

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to create an ArrayList implementation of a stack that supports the method ksum(). ksum() needs to return the sum of the top k elements on the Stack in O(1) time. What algorithm should I use to achieve this?

Currently I am looping through the top k elements and adding their sum in a variable however, this is taking me O(n) time. What is a better way to get the sum of top k elements in a stack in constant time?

Comment: Side note: "O(n)" makes no sense in this statement as there is no "n" anywhere in the text: do you believe that time complexity of your current code is O(number_of_elements_in_stack) or O(k) or something else? Also it is a good idea to clarify if K is fixed or you need to compute sumTop(k) for arbitrary K  in O(1) time (that answer was offered too, but since it is unusual for that assignment to require variable K the answer was self-deleted).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the actual value, add a second variable that tracks the current partial sum. That way, getting the sum of the top `k` elements is simply given by

```
element[last].partial - element[last-k].partial
```

Comment: How would I track the current partial sum?

Comment: @curious That's exactly what this answer is explaining. Can you elaborate on what you're missing?

Comment: @Jorn I don't think this answer explains that.  "Add a second variable that tracks the current partial sum" requires some work to do that this answer doesn't discuss.  (It may be reasonable to leave that as an exercise for the reader, but I don't think it's fair to say this answer explains it.)

Comment: It's pretty trivial IMO. Start by thinking about the sum of an empty stack, then one element, then go from there.

Comment: If the OP is asking, then it's not trivial to them.  Besides, the term "partial sum" is jargon that not everyone knows.

Comment: For some reason I cannot submit an edit right now, so here's a comment: 

This means in your `AddElement` function you need to set the current partial sum to the previous partial sum `+` the added element's value.

Deleting will now run in `O(n)` in the worst case, because you need to update all subsequent elements and subtract the partial sum of the deleted element form them.

Inserting now runs in `O(n)` time, because you need to add the inserted element's value to all subsequent elements.

Comment: Interesting interpretation of `O(1)` as that's theoretically impossible in this case.  With a partial sum array (or class member) the complexity is `O(1)+O(n)/queries` where the second term represents the cost of calculating the partial sum amortized over the number of times the partial sum is queried.  So it's asymptotic to `O(1)` as the number of queries increases.  But yes, this is really splitting hairs, and the partial sum approach is clearly what the writer of the question intended :-)

Comment: I'm looking to solve the problem in O(1) amortized time. Could someone please elaborate on the partial sum method as I'm having difficulties implementing it.

Comment: @curious show your current code and I will update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use integers here. You could store the total sum of the stack from postition `i` in a different `sum` stack at position `i + 1` (the `sum` stack initialy contains the value `0` as it is the neutral element of addition).

When pushing an int element onto your stack you can update your `sum` stack by adding the new total sum (just add your int value and the current top value of the `sum` stack).

Calculating the sum of the top `k` elements can be achived by subtracting the `k + 1` sum value from the top sum value in your `sum` stack.

Here is an example:

```
public class StackNSum {

    private final Stack<Integer> ints = new Stack<>();
    private final Stack<Integer> sums = new Stack<>();

    public StackNSum() {
        sums.push(0);
    }

    public void push(final int number) {
        sums.push(number + sums.peek());
        ints.push(number);
    }

    public int ksum(final int k) {
        // ints.size() - k < 0 need to be handled
        return sums.peek() - sums.get(ints.size() - k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Lukas! This worked! Greatly appreciate your help and time!